# How do I enable VirtualBox guest to access USB 3.0 if the option is grayed out in the settings (after installing the extension pack)?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have created a Windows virtual box with no problems. I'm trying to write to a USB (See at the end more info), but keep getting an error. The Host is a macbook, and the USB is connected through an Apple multiport adapter ([like this one](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-usb-type-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter-white/5596800.p?skuId=5596800&ref=212&loc=1&ref=212&loc=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpfHzBRCiARIsAHHzyZqEHihV3eY0MGU4FZji-ka7dWYfzUxptCGSs-xkC2taRAcDuTEVGZkaAte1EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)). I installed the extension pack successfully but now I can't switch the VB to USB 2 or 3, because the option is grayed out!

[image]

As far as I can tell, I need to add USB 3 or 2 to support this USB. Any help?

---

More info: ultimately, I'm trying to create a bootable USB to install windows in a new machine. As far as I can tell, this cannot be done from OS X anymore (Older solutions included using Bootcamp, which doesn't work anymore or copying the .iso directly to the USB which doesn't work anymore because it contains files larger than 4GB, which is not supported by FAT32).

Comment: What version of VirtualBox? What model/year Mac? What is the model/year of the machine you wish to install Windows on? What version of Windows? 32 bit? 64 bit? Home/Pro/other? XP SP2/Vista/7 SP1/8/8.1/10?

Comment: The 4 GB problem for Macs has been fixed by Apple for some time now.